# ASP.NET Routing without MVC?

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to make use of ASP.NET routing if not using ASP.NET MVC? It seems like a better solution than URL rewriting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, starting with ASP.NET 3.5 SP1 the routing capabilities are found in [System.Web.Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc490435%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). See for example [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for info about how to get started.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be more specific on your scenario but overall, yes it is possible to use Routing wihtout the context of MVC, I have never done that (never had to) but if ever have the scenario to build better looking URLs and have my boilerplate code reduced, that is a good option.